# Python FiPy execution error for example circle.py

Tags: python, installation, incompatibility, fipy

On Windows 10 I'm running Python 3.7 with the current FiPy version 3.4.2.1.

If I run `circle.py` I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circle.py", line 182, in <module>
    exec(fipy.tests.doctestPlus._getScript())
  File "<string>", line 39, in <module>
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 1601, in __init__
    background=background)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 137, in openMSHFile
    raise EnvironmentError("Gmsh version must be >= 2.0.")
OSError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0.
```

The version of gmsh is 4.7.1. Checking what happens in `C:\python37\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py` shows, that the command `version = _gmshVersion(communicator=communicator)` results in `'0.0'`. So I 'hacked' the code to ignore the version.

Now I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circle.py", line 182, in <module>
    exec(fipy.tests.doctestPlus._getScript())
  File "<string>", line 39, in <module>
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 1602, in __init__
    background=background)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 220, in openMSHFile
    stdout=PIPE)
  File "C:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

In English approximately: System cannot find the requested file

Now I'm lost. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I missed that gmsh is an external software that has to beinstaled separately.

After doing this, all runs perfect.